# Shopware6 filter for empty JSON array

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to filter (in a command) all orders without any tracking code attached but I don't know how to apply a filter with this as the `EqualsFilter` does not accept an array as input.

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addAssociation('deliveries');
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('deliveries.trackingCodes', [])); #does not work
$orders = $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $this->context);
```

Providing the actual db field value like `'[]'` as second parameter does not work either and also `null` does not work.
So my question is:
**How can I apply a filter to get all orders with an empty list of tracking codes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the EqualsFilter you should use the ContainsFilter.

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addAssociation('deliveries');
$criteria->addFilter(new ContainsFilter('deliveries.trackingCodes', '[]'));
$orders = $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $this->context);
```

Comment: Indeed, this works like a charm. Not very intuitive though.